# Calculating the date from a series of consecutive time data (R)

Tags: r, date, time-series, lubridate

I have a column of consecutive times (hours, minutes, seconds) with unequal intervals that extends over multiple days.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)    
df <- data.frame(Data  = c(1:10),
                     Time = hms(c("10:00:00","15:38:44","22:12:37",
                                  "23:59:00","00:07:28","04:56:00",
                                  "08:01:25","12:10:54","16:08:43",
                                  "20:44:44")))
```

I want to create a new column with the combined date and time, assuming the first data point was taken on 01.01.2020 at 10:00:00. So, for instance, data point 8 would get "02.01.2020 12:10:54".

My attempts to solve this have not been worth posting here, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks so much!

Comment: #add date:  
df$date <- rep("dates", 10)

#combine date and time in a new column:  
df$newCol <- paste(df$date, df$Time, sep = " ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky but here's a solution:

```
require(tidyverse)    
require(lubridate)

dataf <- tibble(Data  = c(1:16),
                 Time = hms(c("10:00:00","15:38:44","22:12:37",
                              "23:59:00","00:07:28","04:56:00",
                              "08:01:25","12:10:54","16:08:43",
                              "20:44:44","00:07:28","04:56:00",
                              "08:01:25","12:10:54","16:08:43",
                              "20:44:44")))

dataf_2 <- dataf %>% 
  mutate(Data = Data + 1,
         Time_n = as.numeric(Time)) %>% 
  select(Data, Time_n)

dataf %>%
  left_join(dataf_2, by = c("Data")) %>%
  replace_na(list(Time_n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(starting_date = dmy("01/01/2020")) %>% 
  mutate(change_day = if_else(as.numeric(Time) >= Time_n, 0, 1)) %>% 
  arrange(Data) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum=cumsum(change_day),
         t = paste(hour(Time), minute(Time), second(Time))) %>% 
  mutate(final_date = ymd_hms(paste(starting_date + days(cumsum), t))) %>% 
  select(Data, Time, final_date)
```

It will produce an output like this:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
    Data Time        final_date         
   <dbl> <Period>    <dttm>             
 1     1 10H 0M 0S   2020-01-01 10:00:00
 2     2 15H 38M 44S 2020-01-01 15:38:44
 3     3 22H 12M 37S 2020-01-01 22:12:37
 4     4 23H 59M 0S  2020-01-01 23:59:00
 5     5 7M 28S      2020-01-02 00:07:28
 6     6 4H 56M 0S   2020-01-02 04:56:00
 7     7 8H 1M 25S   2020-01-02 08:01:25
 8     8 12H 10M 54S 2020-01-02 12:10:54
 9     9 16H 8M 43S  2020-01-02 16:08:43
10    10 20H 44M 44S 2020-01-02 20:44:44
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very promising! It is almost working but fails where there are two or more identical times. Is it possible to solve that using your solution?

Example:

```dataf <- tibble(Data  = c(1:16),
                 Time = hms(c("10:00:00","15:38:44","22:12:37",
                              "23:59:00","00:07:28","04:56:00",
                              "08:01:25","12:10:54","16:08:43",
                              "20:44:44","00:07:28","04:56:00",
                              "04:56:00","12:10:54","16:08:43",
                              "20:44:44")))```

Comment: You're right. Just replace if_else(as.numeric(Time) > Time_n, 0, 1) with if_else(as.numeric(Time) >= Time_n, 0, 1). I edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    lag = lag(Time),
    diff = Time - lag,
    add_days = if_else(is.na(diff), 0, if_else(diff < 0, 1, 0)),
    add_days_cum = cumsum(add_days),
    date = ymd("2020-01-01") + days(add_days_cum) + Time
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I get the following error message when running your code: "Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  trying to get slot "year" from an object (class "Period") that is not an S4 object"

Comment: That seems strange. It works for me with R 4.0.3 and `lubridate` 1.7.9.2 using your given example dataset. Please make sure that no other packages are loaded so that there are no name conflicts.

Comment: I used RStudio Cloud to test this solution and it worked perfectly - very elegant, thank you. Seems I have some problem with my R installation.